# Power Series of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

In a course I'm taking, we're talking about polynomials of linear operators, i.e. if $E$ is a linear transformation on $V$ and $p$ is a polynomial then we can consider the linear transformation $p(V)$. It seems natural to wish to extend the concept of "function of linear transformation" to functions other than polynomials. Indeed such an example exists in the finite-dimensional case: the matrix exponential. Is there a more general treatment of, for example, analytic functions and everywhere-convergent power series applied to linear transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear transformation $A:\ V\to V$ of a finite-dimensional vector space over ${\mathbb C}$ has a finite norm
$$\|A\|:=\sup\bigl\{|Ax|\ \bigm|\ x\in V,\ |x|=1\bigr\}\ .$$
When $A$ is given by a matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis then one has the estimate $$\|A\|\leq\left(\sum_{i,k} |a_{ik}|^2\right)^{1/2}\ .$$
When $f(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\> z^k$ is any power series in the complex variable $z$ with a convergence radius $$\rho>\|A\|$$
then $$f(A):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\>A^k\ ,$$ defined by
$$f(A).x:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\>\bigl(A^k\> x\bigr)\ ,$$
makes sense and is a linear transformation of $V$. Even formulas of the form
$$f(A)={1\over 2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(z) (z I-A)^{-1}\ dz$$ can be envisaged under suitable assumptions about $A$ and $\gamma$.

Further material on this can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus

Note that "functional calculus" takes place in a general Banach algebra setting, which is infinite dimensional. The finite dimensional case is just a simple corollary.

Comment: Is there a reference for such formulas (both the power series and integral)?

Comment: @Julien Clancy: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with certain convergence conditions. Have a look at R. Bhatia, "matrix analysis " http://books.google.co.in/books?id=F4hRy1F1M6QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bhatia&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0QVoUZqwDoKJrQeiloHACA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ